# How Swift unwrap an optional variable? Will unwrapping cause any overhead?

Tags: ios, swift

Recently I study weak and unowned var.  Weak refer to an optional var, but unowned an unempty one. So I am just curious about what the mechanism of unwrapping is.

Thanks everyone.

Comment: An `Optional` in Swift is a simple `enum` with two cases. Unwrapping it is a simple check if its value is `.none` or `.some(T)` - I’d hardly call this „overhead”. You can read some more here - https://hackernoon.com/swift-optionals-explained-simply-e109a4297298

Answer (score 1):

actually this goes back to generic types. the implementation is something like this

```
enum OptionalValue<Wrapped> {
    case none
    case some(Wrapped)
}
```

when you try to unwrap this it checks if it is `none` or not. This is like doing something like this.

```
var possibleInteger: OptionalValue<Int> = .none
possibleInteger = .some(100)
```

so I think there is no significant overhead. It's a simple check.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are twisting all the concepts together into one. I recommend reading this post for `strong`, `weak`, `unowned` references, the article goes into an example and diagrams to show you how the reference types work and how to avoid retain cycles. Give it a go.
https://krakendev.io/blog/weak-and-unowned-references-in-swift

When it comes to unwraping optionals, there are plenty of ways how to do it. Try to grasp the following concepts (there are million sources on Google for this)

- `If let` statement
- `guard` statement
- force unwrapping
- chaining

Basically optionals are enums with case .none and .some(yourWrappedVariable).

Or if you were trying to ask for something really specific, try to edit your question with more detail and you will get better answers, guaranteed.

Comment: Thank for your answering. I also found out this is one simple explanation (https://youtu.be/Q2ux2Gdt8KQ) :)

Comment: There you go, glad I could help. :)